# React Leaflet: Custom event "onClick" for Marker component

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to define a react component for Marker element of 'react-leaflet'. E.g.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import {Marker,useMapEvent } from 'react-leaflet'
import fireIconSvg from './fire-icon.svg'

import L from "leaflet";

const OSLocationMarker = ( {position, onClick} ) => {

  const locationIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: fireIconSvg,
    iconRetinaUrl: fireIconSvg,
    iconAnchor: null,
    popupAnchor: null,
    shadowUrl: null,
    shadowSize: null,
    shadowAnchor: null,
    iconSize: new L.Point(35, 45),
    className: 'location-icon'
});

return (
      <Marker
        data="customdata"
        position={position}
        icon={locationIcon}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
      </Marker>
  );
}

export default OSLocationMarker;
```

By this I want to trigger a function when one click on any OSLocationMarker (there are N markers). OSLocationMarker get the callback function as prop. This does not work. With useMapEvent() leaflet hook i did not get it working.
Why is the function not being called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`onClick` doesn't work anymore in react-leaflet v3.  `useMapEvent(s)` applies to the `map` instance, not to UI components like `Marker`.  To register an event handler on a `Marker`, you need to use the `eventHandlers` prop:

```js
<Marker
  data="customdata"
  position={position}
  icon={locationIcon}
  eventHandlers={{ click: onClick }}
>
</Marker>
```

Comment: Hey Seth, is there another way of doing this? This is not even compiling for me. It's erroring in the colon, saying I show be having a } instead.

Comment: I think that was a typo.  Should be `eventHandlers={{ click: onClick }}`