# how to know when popup is closed in react leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

how to know when popup is closed in react leaflet, i need to detect when the popup is closed to emit to the server side to stop streaming. so i need to know how when the popup is close. and onclick and on close are not a functions in react leaflet.

```
  <MapContainer  className ='map-display'center={[31.5, 35]} zoom={8} maxZoom={17} minZoom={7} attributionControl={false} >
    <TileLayer
      url="http://localhost:8000/zzz/clients/mapData/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" // Adjust the URL to match your server endpoint
    />    
     {/* placing zoom on the map and makeing that the map state is saved when clicking on the map container  */}
    <RenderBaseZoom LatLng={latLng( index?index.x?index.x:31.5:31.5,index?index.y?index.y:35:35)} zoom={zoom?zoom:8} setZoom={setZoom} setIndex={setIndex}/>
    
  {positoionList.map((marker, index) => (
      <Marker key={index} position={[marker.x, marker.y]} icon={customIcon} >
        <Popup className="fullscreen-popup" >Camera {index + 1} configuration 
       
          <StreamVideoDiv socket={socket} startEffect={closed} />
          <button className='returnButton' onClick={()=>handleDisconnect()}><FaMapLocationDot /></button>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    ))}
    <MapClickHandler />
    
  </MapContainer>
```

i expect to get a correct function that do something when popup is closed

Comment: Probably something similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076608/react-leaflet-custom-event-onclick-for-marker-component) but using [`popupclose` instead](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup).